# objective-c Table Push view

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I am currently working on a push table View Controller I have a navigation controller on my table view.
I Need To get it to load a push view for my categories:
Movies, Tv Shows, ect . 
I made a second Table-View controller to load the  table Push View I wasn't sure what i needed to do to accomplish this?!... 
This is my code for the second controller I used arrays to load the items;

```js
#import "itemViewController.h"

@interface itemViewController () <UIAlertViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *items;

@end

@implementation itemViewController

//Buttons and Cells View.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

       //Edit/Done Button.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(toggleEditing:)];
    //Add Item.
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(addNewItem:)];
    
    
    
   //The Stuff Below I need to turn into a switch statement to load the right one how can I accomplish this?
//movie
    self.items = @[@{@"name" : @"Avatar"},@{@"name" : @"SharkNado"},@{@"name" : @"Kung Fu Panda"}].mutableCopy;
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Movies";
    /*
//Tv Shows
    self.items = @[@{@"name" : @"Avatar the last Airbender"},@{@"name" : @"Reguluar Show"},@{@"name" : @""}].mutableCopy;
    self.navigationItem.title = @"TV Shows";
    
//Restaurants
    self.items = @[@{@"name" : @""},@{@"name" : @""},@{@"name" : @""}].mutableCopy;
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Restaurants";
    
//Concert Venues
    self.items = @[@{@"name" : @""},@{@"name" : @""},@{@"name" : @""}].mutableCopy;
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Concert Venues";

//Video Games
    self.items = @[@{@"name" : @""},@{@"name" : @""},@{@"name" : @""}].mutableCopy;
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Video Games";

//Foods
    self.items = @[@{@"name" : @""},@{@"name" : @""},@{@"name" : @""}].mutableCopy;
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Food";

//Recipes
    self.items = @[@{@"name" : @"Chocolate Chip Cookies"},@{@"name" : @""},@{@"name" : @""}].mutableCopy;
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Recipes";
  }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

*/

}

//Editing For Delete.
#pragma mark - Editing

- (void)toggleEditing:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    [self.tableView setEditing:!self.tableView.editing animated:YES];
    
    if (self.tableView.editing) {
        sender.title = @"Done";
        sender.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleDone;
    } else {
        sender.title = @"Edit";
        sender.style = UIBarButtonItemStylePlain;
        }
    }




//Adding the Items.
#pragma mark - adding items

- (void) addNewItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Movie" message:@"Please Enter the Title of the New Movie" delegate:self
        cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Add Item", nil];
    alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [alertView show];

}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex != alertView.cancelButtonIndex) {
        UITextField *itemNameField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
        NSString *itemName = itemNameField.text;
        NSDictionary *item = @{@"name" : itemName,};
        [self.items addObject:item];
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:self.items.count - 1 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
}



//Table View Settings.
#pragma mark - Table view datasource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.items.count;
}



//Cell Accessory onclick CheckMark.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Item";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    NSDictionary *item = self.items[indexPath.row];
    
    cell.textLabel.text = item[@"name"];
    if ([item[@"completed"] boolValue]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    
    
    return cell;
}



//table View Delegate.
#pragma mark - Table view delegate
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableDictionary *item = [self.items[indexPath.row] mutableCopy];
    BOOL completed = [item[@"completed"] boolValue];
    item[@"completed" ] = @(!completed);
    
    self.items[indexPath.row] = item;
    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = ([item[@"completed"] boolValue]) ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

//editing
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

//Removes Item

//- (void)tableview:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 //   if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
 //       [self removeItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
 //      [tableView deleteRowAtIndexPaths;@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
 //   }
//}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH8-SW4

Has the complete guide on how to do it!